# Most command prompt commands not working in os.system()

Tags: python, python-2.7, windows-10, command-prompt

I'm pretty new to python and I am learning how to use basic command line operations with `os.system()` (os module)

I haven't been able to use TASKKILL recently and I need it for a python script I'm working on.
When I try to use TASKKILL in command prompt separately it doesn't work either. Only when I open the command prompt as administrator does it work.
The error I get:

```
'TASKKILL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I'm currently using Windows 10 and Python 2.7.13, would appreciate anyone's help.

Thank you

Comment: It's not necessary to repeat tag information in the title. The tag system works extremely well here. Taskkill requires admin credentials, which requires an administrative console (command prompt). If you aren't running in an elevated command prompt, it's not going to work. This is not a Python issue; it's a simple operating system permissions issue.

Comment: Ok Is there any way I can access os.system() with administrative priveledges? @KenWhite

Comment: @BaburAhmed Yeah, open an elevated command prompt and run the script in it.